# Whats the fastest way to loop through a DataFrame and count occurrences within the DataFrame whilst some condition is fulfilled (in Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, while-loop

I have a dataframe with two Boolean fields (as below).

```
import pandas as pd

d = [{'a1':False, 'a2':False}, {'a1':True, 'a2':False}, {'a1':True, 'a2':False}, {'a1':False, 'a2':False}, {'a1':False, 'a2':True},
     {'a1': False, 'a2': False}, {'a1':False, 'a2':False}, {'a1':True, 'a2':False}, {'a1':False, 'a2':True}, {'a1':False, 'a2':False},]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

Out[1]: 
      a1     a2
0  False  False
1   True  False
2   True  False
3  False  False
4  False   True
5  False  False
6  False  False
7   True  False
8  False   True
9  False  False
```

I am trying to find the fastest and most "Pythonic" way of achieving the following:

- If a1==True, count instances from current row where a2==False (e.g. row 1: a1=True, a2 is False for three rows from row 1)
- At first instance of a2==True, stop counting (e.g. row 4, count = 3)
- Set value of 'count' to new df column 'a3' on **row where counting began** (e.g. 'a3' = 3 on row 1)

Target result set as follows.

```
      a1     a2  a3
0  False  False   0
1   True  False   3
2   True  False   2
3  False  False   0
4  False   True   0
5  False  False   0
6  False  False   0
7   True  False   1
8  False   True   0
9  False  False   0
```

I have been trying to accomplish this using for loops, iterrows and while loops and so far haven't been able to produce a good nested combination which provides the results I want. Any help appreciated. I apologize if the problem is not totally clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
df['a3'] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if not x.a1 else len(df.a2[x.name:df.a2.tolist()[x.name:].index(True)+x.name]), axis=1)
```

So, if a1 is `False` write `0` else write the length of list that goes from that row until next `True`.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
df['a3'] = 0
# loop throught every value of 'a1'
for i in xrange(df['a1'].__len__()):
    # if 'a1' at position i is 'True'...
    if df['a1'][i] == True:
        count = 0
        # loop over the remaining items in 'a2'
        # remaining: __len__() - i
        # i: position of 'True' value in 'a1'
        for j in xrange(df['a2'].__len__() - i):
            # if the value of 'a2' is 'False'...
            if df['a2'][j + i] == False:
                # count the occurances of 'False' values in a row...
                count += 1
            else:
                # ... if it's not 'False' break the loop
                break
        # write the number of occurances on the right position (i) in 'a3'
        df['a3'][i] = count
```

and produce the following output:

```
      a1     a2  a3
0  False  False   0
1   True  False   3
2   True  False   2
3  False  False   0
4  False   True   0
5  False  False   0
6  False  False   0
7   True  False   1
8  False   True   0
9  False  False   0
```

---

Edit: added comments in the code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll have to go through line by line to see how the nesting for/ifs produce the correct answer as this is what I was originally going for. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, sorry I haven't explained my code well... Edited the code with comments.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the comments.